# How to manage different timezone for a model in Laravel (4.2).

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, eloquent

In my Laravel (4.2) based application, I have a user model. and users belongs to some different timezone. For some reason, when data is saved to database, it uses server timezone. now, I have to display dates, according to their timezone. How can I do it easily? Thanks.

Comment: Save datetimes in UTC.  Then adjust to client's timezone

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested I suggest you take a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY